# Copy iTunes Playlists from old to new Mac

Tags: itunes

My music is already copied onto new Mac AND into iTunes, but it is not organized into the several hundred playlists I have.  How do I get those playlists from old Mac to new Mac (and ensure the songs are placed in the playlists)?

Answer (score 1):

## Save a copy of your playlists from iTunes on macOS

You can export a playlist—for example, if you want to save a copy of the playlist, or import it to a different computer so you have the same playlist in both places.

You can also export information about a song *(or songs)* to use in a database or in another app.

When you export playlists or transfer song information, the actual songs or videos aren’t included—just the information about them or the playlist.

### Save copies of playlists or use playlists on another computer

Do any of the following:

- Save a copy of a single playlist or use it in iTunes on another computer: Select the playlist, choose **File** > **Library** > **Export Playlist**, and choose **XML** from the Format pop-up menu.
- Import an iTunes playlist: Choose **File** > **Library** > **Import Playlist**. The imported playlist includes only songs and videos already in your iTunes library. Unavailable items are removed from the list.
- Save a copy of all your playlists: Choose **File** > **Library** > **Export Library**. The exported information is saved in XML format.

### Transfer song information into other applications

Do either of the following:

- Export all the song information into a text file: Select a playlist,
  then choose **File** > **Library** > **Export Playlist**. Make sure Plain Text is selected in the Format pop-up menu *(if you use a double-byte language
  such as Japanese or Chinese, or if the program you’re importing into
  understands Unicode, you should choose Unicode)*.

  All information from the Info window for each song is exported, not just the fields currently displayed in the library or playlist.
- Copy the information (in the columns that are visible) for one or more songs: Select the songs and choose **Edit** > **Copy**, and then choose **Edit** > **Paste** in another application *(for example, an email or text document)*.

Comment: Did you find this answer solve your question @lisa-v ? If so, could you please mark it as accepted? :)